# How to prevent android studio gradle from auto downloading emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When creating new projects with android studio Flamingo 2022.2.1, gradle 8.0, it automatically starts downloading emulator

```
...
:prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel
...
Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: xx.x.x)"
```

I have an android device connected. I do not need a new emulator. How to bypass this annoying "Preparing"?

It also installs another build-tools 33.0.2, totally ignoring my existing tools of version 30.0.3.

And the project is a pure java project, the gradle build scripts are in Groovy, there is no relationship between my project and kotlin, why is there a task named "prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel"? I can remember such task didn't exist a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent Android Studio from automatically downloading the emulator, you can disable the "Android Emulator" option in the Android SDK Manager.

Here are the steps:

1. Open Android Studio and click on "SDK Manager" in the toolbar (or go to "File" -> "Settings" -> "Appearance & Behavior" -> "System Settings" -> "Android SDK").
2. In the "SDK Platforms" tab, uncheck the "Android Emulator" option.
3. Click "Apply" to save the changes.

This should prevent Android Studio from automatically downloading the emulator.

Regarding the installation of build-tools 33.0.2, this may be happening because the Android Gradle plugin you are using requires that version of the build tools. You can check which version of the Android Gradle plugin you are using in your project by looking at the build.gradle file. If you want to use a different version of the build tools, you can specify it in your build.gradle file using the buildToolsVersion property.

As for the "prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel" task, it is a new task introduced in Gradle 6.0. The task is responsible for generating the Kotlin build script model, which is used to configure the Kotlin plugin for Gradle. Even if your project is a pure Java project and you are not using the Kotlin plugin, this task will still be executed by Gradle. However, you can safely ignore this task if you are not using the Kotlin plugin.

Comment: All 8 of your answers this month appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.